# Supertest don't close Koa server after tests

Tags: node.js, jestjs, koa, supertest, koa2

I have koa `app` and jest test framework, `app` wrapped by `http.createServer` and connect to mongo

```
mongooseConnect();

const app = new Koa();

initHandlers(app);

app.use(routes);

export default http.createServer(app.callback());
```

After tests supertest don't close server, test example

```
test('success create user', (done) => {
      return supertest(app)
        .post(`/api/auth/signup`)
        .send(userData)
        .expect(200)
        .expect({
          data: {
            email: userData.email,
            firstName: userData.firstName.toLowerCase(),
            lastName: userData.lastName.toLowerCase(),
            bio: userData.bio,
          },
        }, done);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually close the server:

```
      },
    }, () => {
    app.close()
    done()
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

After all tests close mongoose connection

```
afterAll(async (done) => {
  await closeMongoConnection();
  done();
});
```

closeMongoConnection:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export default () => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    res(mongoose.connection.close());
  });
};
```

Comment: This is asking about the Koa server not the mongoose connection.